# “Even if” at the start of a negative sentence

Tags: conditionals

I saw this msg on wishesmsg where it was written-
You two proved that even if life’s not perfect as a movie, having a loving partner is every trouble worthy.

I am not sure if this makes any sense. Please help[image]

Comment: A negative assertion is still an assertion.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question here is. I'm not sure what the quoted sentence is intending to say but it's not good English.

Comment: @KillingTime I think the original poster of the message meant "You two have proved that, even if life is not **as** perfect as a movie, having a loving partner is **worth all the** trouble." Unfortunately they have mangled it quite badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the message to be “You two proved that even if life’s not as perfect as a movie, having a loving partner is worth every trouble.”

I continue my answer, even if my assumption is not quite correct. (= I continue my answer, despite knowing that my assumption may be incorrect.)

The message is addressed to a couple (“you two”) who live together. The person who wrote the message comments that “Even if life is not as perfect as ...” (=“despite life not being as perfect as ...”), the couple’s life demonstrates that the value of love is greater than the troubles of life (or of living together; the sentence is not clear about what troubles are referred to).